# help with null pointer exception in Java

Tags: java

I am putting together a simple simulated network in java, where i can add computers, servers, and connect two objects with ethernet ports.   This is where the null pointer exception is being thrown, when i call "this.etherPort.addElement(t);"

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Server extends Computer{

     public Vector<Ethernet> etherPort; 

     public void addPort(Ethernet t)
  {
   this.etherPort.addElement(t);
  }
}
```

This code is run when i make a new Ethernet object using this code:

```
public class Ethernet {
```

public Computer terminal1, terminal2;
 public int volume;
    public Ethernet(Computer term, Server term2)
     {
  this.terminal1 = term;
  this.terminal2 = (Computer) term2;
  if(term != null)
  {
   term.addPort(this);
  }
  if(term2 != null)
  {
   term2.addPort(this);
  }
 }
    }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to instanciate your etherPort member :

```
public class Server extends Computer{

     public Vector<Ethernet> etherPort = new Vector<Ethernet>(); 

     public void addPort(Ethernet t)
     {
        this.etherPort.addElement(t);
     }
}
```

You should make sure that addPort() is not overriding a method called from your Computer constructor, though. Given the context, I assume it's safe (*i.e.* Computer has no addPort() method).

As stated below in a comment, it's generally better to use interfaces that don't constrain the containers implementations : you'd better declare etherPort as a

```
List<Ethernet>
```

instead of a

```
Vector<Ethernet>
```

and use etherPort.add(element) instead of the Vector-specific addElement method.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't initialize the vector. Should be:

```
public Vector<Ethernet> etherPort = new Vector<Ethernet>();
```

Comment: Should probably be private final List<Ethernet> etherPorts = new ArrayList<Ethernet>(); The final would have caught the error.

Answer (score 2):

etherPort is null.  You are apparently never initializing it with an actual Vector.  I think you want:

```
public class Server extends Computer{

     public Vector<Ethernet> etherPort; 

     public Server()
     {
        etherPort = new Vector<Ethernet>();
     }

     public void addPort(Ethernet t)
     {
        this.etherPort.addElement(t);
     }
}
```